# Nature of stationary points

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

I have

$$f(x_1,x_2) = 2x^4_1 + 2x_1x_2 + 2x_1 + (1+x_2)^2$$

How can I **determine the nature of the stationary points**?

I know;

$$f_{x_1,x_1}(x) = 24x_1^2$$
$$f_{x_2,x_2}(x) = 2$$
$$f_{x_1,x_2}(x) = 2$$

This gives me a hessian:

$$ \nabla^2 f(x) = 
 \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     24x_1^2 & 2 \\
     2 & 2
  \end{array} \right]
$$

By examining the leading principal minors;
$$D_1 = \| (24x_1^2)\| \geq 0$$ and $$D_2 = 
\det\left|\array{24x_1^2&2\\2&2}\right|  = 48x_1^2 -4$$

Since I have no condition on $x_1^2$ then $D_2$ can be positive, negative or even 0.

So then does this mean this matrix is indefinite, and hence all the stationary points here are saddle points?

Have I made a mistake in the Hessian? I feel the $24x_1^2$ term is out of place.

any help is VERY MUCH appreciated.

Comment: The stationary points satisfy $\nabla f(x_1,x_2) = 0$; that should tell you what $x_1$ is at each.

Comment: I know what each of the stationary points are, but to determine the type of stationary point, I have to examine the hessian - is that not correct?

The stationary points I worked out as
$(0,-1), (\frac{1}{2}, \frac{-3}{2}), (\frac{-1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$

It was my understanding to figure out the nature of the stationary points, one must examine the 2nd derivatives.

Comment: Yes, the $x_1$ in $D_2$ is the first coordinate of the stationary point.  So you will get a number at each point.

Answer (score 1):

We have
\begin{align*}
f_{x_1} (x_1,x_2) &= 2x_1^4 + 2x_2 +2 \\
f_{x_2} (x_1,x_2) &= 2x_1 + 2(x_2 + 1) \\
\end{align*}
So if $(x_1,x_2)$ is a critical point we have
\begin{align}
8x_1^3 + 2x_2 +2  &= 0 \\
2x_1 + 2x_2 + 2   &= 0 
\end{align}
Subtracting the two gives
$$
8x_1^3 - 2x_1 = 0 = 4x_1(4x_1^2-1)
$$
therefore $x_1 = 0, \pm \frac{1}{2}$.  The critical points are $(0,-1)$, $\left(\frac{1}{2},-\frac{3}{2}\right)$, and $\left(-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\right)$.

You have already computed that that $D_1 > 0$ if $x_1 \neq 0$, and in this case $D_2 = 48 \cdot \frac{1}{4} - 4 = 8$.  So these two points are local minima.  $D_2 < 0$ at $(0,0)$ so this critical point is a saddle point.

[Here is a contour plot](http://wolfr.am/2P_Y3~xK) to see what's going on:

[image: contour plot of $f$]

Comment: I did all the work, and completely forgot to substitute in the points - I am not wise. Thanks matthew, you legend!

Comment: @diabloescobar nope, just a professional calculus teacher.